# Select a column by another table's value in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have Table **users**:

```
user_id | lang_id
--------+---------
 12345  |    en 
 54321  |    ru
 77777  |    uz
```

and Table **texts**:

```
text_id |   en   |   ru    |   uz
--------+--------+---------+-------
   hi   | Hello! | Привет! | Salom!
  bye   |  Bye!  |  Пока!  | Xayr!
```

I have two informations:

> user_id = 12345 
>   text_id = 'hi'

and I'm trying this query, to get a text for user's chosen language:

```
SELECT (SELECT lang_id FROM users WHERE user_id = 12345) FROM texts
WHERE text_id = 'hi'
```

and getting this:

```
lang_id
------
  en
```

> I should get the text "Hello!"

I'm kinda newbie in PostgreSQL would be good if you help me to solve this :)

Comment: You can only do this through a dynamic query, the right way would be to proper design your database. User is fine, texts though should be either (text_id, language, text) or you should have a table languages like `language (id, lang)` a table `text (id, text)` and a relational between both: `text_lang (id_text, id_lang)` The way you designed will make you repeat data not to say adding a new column for every new language... last I check there are roughly 6,500 different languages/dialects. You don't want a table with that many columns

Comment: Read about [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) it will help you understand how you should proper design your databases...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I 100% recommend changing your schema to something properly normalized like Jorge Campos suggests up in the comments, you can use some hard coding in a `CASE` statement to get at your texts.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN users.lang_id = 'en' THEN texts.en
        WHEN users.lang_id = 'ru' THEN texts.ru
        WHEN users.lang_id = 'uz' THEN texts.uz
        END as user_language_text
FROM
    users, texts
WHERE
    user_id = 12345
    AND text_id = 'hi';
```

There are some major downsides here though:

1. That CASE statement is costly from a CPU perspective
2. To determine which column in `texts` from which you retrieve your data you have to hard code the possibly language values. Meaning every time you add a new language not only do you have to add a new column to your table (major anti-pattern by itself) but you also have to tweak ALL of your SQL to accommodate.
3. You must cross join (or subquery without correlation) to derive the relationship between your `texts` and the user's `lang_id`. If `lang_id` were a column in your text table you would join there and just pick up values in your `texts` table that correspond to the user's `lang_id`.

Again. I would highly highly encourage you to rethink your schema since this has you headed toward a nightmare that won't scale, will cause you to constantly edit your schema, and hard code values in your SQL.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 4):

Well the simplest way is to cast row to json and then access field dynamically. It is very similar to your original query:

```
select row_to_json(t.*)->(select lang_id 
                            from users 
                           where user_id = 12345) 
  from texts t 
 where text_id = 'hi'
```

Comment: I also think that best way is just to normalize you schema. But anyway it is a nice trick to know.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's incorrect approach to develop localization. You can make table `texts`
with parameters `text_id`, `lang_id` and `text`. And it can help to develop more flexible

In your case you can do it

```
SELECT 
  case 
    when u.user_id = 'en' then t.en
    when u.user_id = 'ru' then t.ru
    when u.user_id = 'uz' then t.uz
    else t.en
  end as text
FROM texts as t
left join lateral (
  SELECT lang_id 
  FROM users 
  WHERE user_id = 12345
) as u on true 
WHERE text_id = 'hi'
```